# Ionic 3 - Parámetros en ion-select

Tags: ionic3

Tengo en `Ionic 3` un `ion-select` que completo desde un archivo `JSON`

```
{"records":
  [
    {
      "**PaisD**" : "Afganistán", 
      "**ID**": "AF"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

El select se completa perfecto, y muestra **PaisD**.

Ahora bien, cuando cambio la selección (***ionChange***) quiero que ambos valores, **ID** y **PaisD** pasen como parámetros a una función, pero no logro hacerlo. En $event solo se encuentra **PaisD**. Les paso el código para ver si me pueden ayudar por favor, muchas gracias

```
<ion-select formControlName="country" (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
<ion-option *ngFor="let pais of paises" [value]="pais.id">{{pais.PaisD}}
</ion-option>
</ion-select>

onChange($event){
  alert($event);
}
```

Comment: Teniendo el ID, es más sencillo buscar en el array `this.paises` el elemento que coincide: `onChange(id) {let pais=this.paises.filter(p=>p.id==id); ...}`

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Funcionando perfecto !